# Make line "stop" when it intersects object

Tags: java, java-2d

So I am making this top-down game where there are zombies and your player can shoot them. From the player there is a red line (like a laser) that shows which direction you are pointing. I wanted this laser to act like a real laser - if there is a object in the way it will only go as far as that object. Also I am not really sure how to make the laser go through the mouse pointer and keep going to the edge of the window (unless object in the way). I have an ArrayList called entities which contains all of my objects (Class = Entity) that I render.

```
Player p = (Player) entities.get(0);
g.setColor(Color.RED);
g.drawLine((int)p.getX(), (int)p.getY(), getMouseX(), getMouseY());
```

That code just makes a line that goes to the point of the Cursor (as expected) from the Players location. Bear in mind that the enemies are circles (I have a method to check if a point is in a circle)

```
public boolean isPointInCircle(double centerX, double centerY, double radius, double x, double y){
    boolean isInRectangle = x >= centerX - radius && x <= centerX + radius && y >= centerY - radius && y <= centerY + radius;
    if(isInRectangle){
        double dx = centerX - x;
        double dy = centerY - y;
        dx *= dx;
        dy *= dy;
        double distanceSquared = dx + dy;
        double radiusSquared = radius * radius;
        return distanceSquared <= radiusSquared;
    }
    return false;
}
```

I tried to go about this by sending an invisible "bullet" at the gradient of the line but it failed so I gave up on that. So my two questions are:

**How do I make the line go in the direction of the mouse but keep going to the edge of the frame?**

**... Unless it intersects with an Entity, at which point it will only go as far as the Entity?**

Comment: Simple way is brute force: Google how to check if line intersects with a circle, and check against every entity. If none intersect, draw to intersection of line and edge (again google to learn the math). Maybe someone will write these formulas, perhaps with Java code, as answer so you don't have to google :)

Comment: Yeah im not sure it will be efficient at all

Comment: Unless you have thousands of entities, it is easily efficient enough. And if not, time to learn about [BSP trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_space_partitioning) or some other way to optimize.